# How to convert d into 64bit limbs?

Tags: ed25519

Given a d value = -(10240/10241)

How would I convert this into 64 bit limbs?

I have to expand on this because of stackoverflow quality algorithm, I've tried using python to get the integer rep/hex rep, but it's not a whole number, so I'm a bit lost

Comment: What field are we working in?

Comment: Any field, just want to see the process @SqueamishOssifrage

Comment: Well, if you're talking about the rational numbers, it depends on how you encode them: as numerator/denominator fractions? as fixed-point? as floating-point?  If you're talking about finite fields, look up modular multiplicative inverses.

Comment: Trying to look up if this was about crypto (didn't hear about limbs before, I guess we normally just use "words"), I found [this presentation](https://rwc.iacr.org/2015/Slides/RWC-2015-Longa.pdf) Could you take a look at page 7 to see if it answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is related to the Jubjub Edwards curve, for which `d = -(10240/10241) (mod r = 52435875175126190479447740508185965837690552500527637822603658699938581184513) = 19257038036680949359750312669786877991949435402254120286184196891950884077233`, the four 64-bit limbs (in little-endian order) are:

`(73851820219580081, 2967167836563676454, 17725484271033745364, 3067823152860638024)`

The "process" is pretty simple:

- `73851820219580081 = d mod 2^64`
- `2967167836563676454 = (d / 2^64) mod 2^64`
- `17725484271033745364 = (d / 2^128) mod 2^64`
- `3067823152860638024 = (d / 2^192) mod 2^64`